# Umbraco 4.6: Get Node by Version

Tags: umbraco

I am trying to get a previous version of a published node to do comparison to the current node.  I have found Document.GetContentFromVersion but can't seem to find the equivalent in NodeFactory or a way to convert Content to a Node type.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent to Document.GetContentFromVersion in NodeFactory as NodeFactory gets its data from the umbraco.config cache and Document pulls it's data from the database (See [Difference Between Node and Document](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/difference-between-node-and-document)).

You can get at the properties of a Content object the same way you would with a Document or a Node:

```
var old = Document.GetContentFromVersion(version);
var oldProperty = old.getProperty("propertyAlias");
```

For comparisons,
Node:

```
var nodeProperty = node.GetProperty("propertyAlias");

if (oldProperty.Value == nodeProperty.Value)
{
    ...
}
```

Document:

```
var docProperty = node.getProperty("propertyAlias");
if (oldProperty.Value == docProperty.Value)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's what I figured.  The reason I asked was I was hoping to reuse a method which currently takes a Node type for its argument.  There are several ways to skin this cat.  I was just hoping it would be a simple type cast I was missing.  :-)  Thanks.